# Vue.js router redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've a method that looks like this:

```
methods: {
        search () {
            this.$route.router.go({ name: 'Search', Params: { search: this.searchFor }});
        }
    }
```

Obviously that is not working. How could I get that to work? I'm using `vue.js 1.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1.0/docs/en/api/go.md), the `Params` should be `params`